# Spark 2.4 application throws parquet error

Tags: apache-spark

I get this exception in the spark application submitted with spark-submit (2.4.0)

> User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Multiple sources found for parquet (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.DefaultSource), please specify the fully qualified class name.;

**My application is:**

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName(APP_NAME)
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
sparkSession.sql(query)
```

I'm unable to figure out where this duplicate source for parquet is coming from:

**Here is my spark-submit:**

> spark-submit-2.4.0 --master yarn-cluster \
>   --files="/etc/hive/hive-site.xml" \
>   --driver-class-path="/etc/hadoop/:/usr/lib/spark-packages/spark2.4.0/jars/*:/usr/lib/spark-packages/spark2.4.0/lib/spark-assembly.jar:/usr/lib/hive/lib/*"

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Hello @BiN try not to import more parquet .jar files than those Spark already has. The folders you are including with spark-submit it looks that probably have more of same jar files but different versions.

Answer (score 2):

There was a mixup with the version of spark-submit (2.4) that I was using and the default SPARK_HOME pointing to an older version, just in case anyone else has the same issue.